# Sharepoint 2013 : some REST API's are not working

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 server on which I created a site and shared it with demo users.
Those users can do activities like adding conversation and replying to it.
also other activities like "Like", "follow", etc are available.

But when I try to fetch this data using REST API's then it doen't work.

some API works (like "social.following/my/followers") and some doesn't (like "social.feed/my/likes", "social.feed/my/feed")

Kindly help me and let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: any suggestion please?

Comment: post your code please… and what doesn't seem to work?  are you getting an error message?